# combine between with any other sql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine between query with other query in sql syntax, I want to show data with

```
SELECT * 
FROM tx_log 
WHERE (tx_command = 'prepaid-response' AND tx_status = 'OK') 
OR (tx_command = 'postpaid-response' AND tx_status = 'OK') 
OR (tx_command = 'cek-response' AND tx_status = 'NOK') 
  AND tx_timestamp between '2016-09-19 00:00:01' and '2016-09-20 00:00:01';
```

syntax above it's clear not showing error message, but the data displayed does not match the specified date. In above I will showing data from 2016-09-19 until 2016-09-20, but date other than it actually appears.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tx_log 
WHERE ((tx_command = 'prepaid-response' AND tx_status = 'OK') 
OR (tx_command = 'postpaid-response' AND tx_status = 'OK') 
OR (tx_command = 'cek-response' AND tx_status = 'NOK')) 
AND tx_timestamp between '2016-09-19 00:00:01' and '2016-09-20 00:00:01';
```

You miss the outer bracket `()`. when all OR conditions end.

Comment: oh god yeah it's work, thank you. and good simple explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tx_log 
WHERE ( (tx_command = 'prepaid-response' AND tx_status = 'OK') 
OR (tx_command = 'postpaid-response' AND tx_status = 'OK') 
OR (tx_command = 'cek-response' AND tx_status = 'NOK') )
  AND tx_timestamp between '2016-09-19 00:00:01' and '2016-09-20 00:00:01';
```

If any of the conditions joined by `OR` returns `true` then that row will be included in result no matter whether other conditions return `true` or `false`. Wrap all the conditions joined by `OR` into a single condition as given above in my query.

Answer (score 1):

"AND" has precedence over "OR"
so your query reads:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tx_log 
WHERE (tx_command = 'prepaid-response' AND tx_status = 'OK') 
OR (tx_command = 'postpaid-response' AND tx_status = 'OK') 
OR ( (tx_command = 'cek-response' AND tx_status = 'NOK') 
      AND tx_timestamp between '2016-09-19 00:00:01' and '2016-09-20 00:00:01'
   )
```

So the timestamp filter is only applied to the "last" or condition

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tx_log 
WHERE (
       (tx_command = 'prepaid-response' AND tx_status = 'OK') 
    OR (tx_command = 'postpaid-response' AND tx_status = 'OK') 
    OR (tx_command = 'cek-response' AND tx_status = 'NOK')
    ) 
    AND tx_timestamp between '2016-09-19 00:00:01' and '2016-09-20 00:00:01'
```